# Remote debugging for Android in XDK

Tags: android, remote-debugging, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to debug an app from XDK with Chrome Remote Debugging. I've followed the steps in [Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) but the app doesn't appear in `chrome://inspect/#devices` under my device.

I'm pretty sure that contents debugging enabled should be set to true as it is suggested there:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

I don't know how to enable this in a XDK app. Please, any help?

**EDIT**

I've seen this related commit to cordova: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;h=ea1f041
I don't know if it is applicable to XDK as well. I've tried to set this preference in `intelxdk.config.additions.xml` but it's not working:

```
<preference name="debuggable" value="true"/>
```

Also I've tried to install chrome and remote debugging is working fine with it. So then
I've tried to install this plugin with no result: https://github.com/jrstarke/webview-debug

**EDIT-2**

env: Android 4.4 Cyanogenmod-11
Cordova 3.6 has the same problem (even with `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `<preference name="debuggable" value="true"/>` option to your intelxdk.config.additions.xml file.

Remote Chrome DevTools debugging of a webview app (which is what you're doing with Cordova and the Intel XDK) requires the Chrome webview found in Android 4.4 and later devices. Thus, this will not work with an Android device running 4.3 or lower.

If you build with Crosswalk you can debug on Android 4.0 or higher devices.

The version of the webview your Cordova app is running in determines the ability to utilize remote CDT for debugging. In the native (builin) webview that means you need Android 4.4, because that is the first webview based on Chrome (which is what makes this work). Crosswalk is based on Chromium, and runs on Android 4.0 and above, thus the reason you can use it to debug on Android 4.0 and higher devices.

Comment: This is a cordova 3.5 issue or XDK? I've been searching for Cordova bug but haven't found anyone... In fact cordova is announcing it is possible in their [docs for 3.5](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_next_index.md.html#Debugging) and [for 3.6](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_next_index.md.html#Debugging). The only related bug I found is [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5487) but it seems to be solved in 3.5

Comment: The 3.5 problem is an XDK build issue, not a Cordova build issue. I was told today that it is now available on our staging site, but I have not had a chance to check that out (due to travel). I hope to verify this week, and expect that it will be available on the main build site for 3.5 Android builds by the end of the week.

Comment: UPDATE: we no longer support Cordova 3.5, but this feature does continue to work with our current build systems, and will continue to work for the foreseeable future. It is a Chrome feature that you're using.